# U-SQL Extract Statement - working with hundreds of columns

Tags: azure, u-sql

Is there any way in the U-SQL extract statement to only specify the input columns that I care about?  I'm working with a legacy database that exports several tables to csv that has about 200 columns.  I only care about 10 of those fields.  I was hoping to do something like:

```
EXTRACT CustomerID:0   string,
    StoreNumber:5    double,
    ReceiptNumber:20   double,
    Timestamp:125   int
FROM "somefile.csv"
USING Extractors.Csv();
```

So the idea would be to specify an index that corresponds to which column the data comes from.

Is there anything like that in the works? Or do I always need to define all 200 columns?  I'm open to other solutions as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your custom extractor code. Use the sample extractors at https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats as guidance.

Comment: Although it's not possible to do what I described above, it's easy enough through a custom extractor as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Haven't the solution still not introduced in U-SQL as an in-built feature instead of custom extractor?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to do this as you describe, but it would not take long to script.  For example I often use Excel to help with scripting, eg paste the known metadata for the 200 column csv then map it to U-SQL data types, eg

[image: Excel U-SQL helper]

You could create an initial [U-SQL view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771901.aspx) that had all the columns using the method above, then create another view based on the initial view for the columns you want:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS dbo.view1
    AS
EXTRACT col1 int,
        col2 string,
        col3 string,
        col4 string,
        col5 string
FROM "/input/input44.txt"
USING Extractors.Csv();


CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS dbo.view2
    AS
SELECT  col1,
        col2
FROM dbo.view1;


@input =
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.view2;
```

I also sometimes use Visual Studio [Find and Replace with RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) to do similar things.